# Какая есть альтернатива этому коду?

Tags: python, инспекция-кода, чистый-код

```
while True:
    try:
        ...
        break
    except:
        continue
```

Есть ли более элегантное решение ?

Comment: Лучшая альтернатива коду - никакого кода. А если серьезно, то объясните поподробнее, что у вас за процесс, что его окружает, в чем смысл и т.п. А то вдруг вы гвозди микроскопом вообще забиваете )

Comment: @Kromster Делаю скрипт на селениуме. Там нужно дождаться появления определенной кнопки на сайте, и чтобы не ставить time.sleep, сделал обработчик ошибки selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException в цикле, пока кнопка не появится

Comment: Вносите уточнения прямо в тело вопроса

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть довольно старый пакет [retrying](https://github.com/rholder/retrying), много где он установлен по умолчанию, например, в Google Colab. Адаптированный под `Python 3` пример из документации с использованием декоратора `@retry`:

```
import random
from retrying import retry

@retry
def do_something_unreliable():
    if random.randint(0, 10) > 1:
        raise IOError("Broken sauce, everything is hosed!!!111one")
    else:
        return "Awesome sauce!"

print(do_something_unreliable())
```

Наверняка этот декоратор внутри себя по сути делает тоже самое, что и ваш код, другое тут что-то сложно придумать. Там только есть ещё всякие настройки - можно настроить число повторных попыток, паузы между попытками и т.п. При использовании параметров по умолчанию этот декоратор в точности повторяет логику вашего кода. Т.е. вам нужно вынести код, который может бросить `Exception`, в отдельную функцию и задекорировать её декоратором `@retry`, остальное сделает декоратор. В таком виде код будет более красив и понятен, чем с лишними `try/catch` и "вечным циклом":

```
from retrying import retry

@retry
def func():
    # ваш код
```